# Implementing a question analyzer for auto tagging

Tags: algorithm, bayesian, analyzer

What are good resources to go to for implementing a question analyzer?

I am trying to figure out how to auto-tag questions to make it easier for non-technical users to ask questions. I've found that using Bayes Theorem I can achieve this, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Any open source libraries or research papers on this?

Comment: Are you looking for open source Bayesian classifiers ? Are you looking for supervised / unsupervised learning ?

Comment: Open source Bayesian classifiers would be nice to have.

I'm looking for the best way to implement this. I believe unsupervised learning would allow the system to grow rather than being provisioned by a person.

Answer (score 3):

Naive Bayes probabilistic classifiers are commonly-used in text categorization. The basic idea is to use the joint probabilities of words and categories to estimate the probabilities of categories given a document. The naive part of such a model is the assumption of word independence. The simplicity of this assumption makes the computation of the Naive Bayes classifier far more efficient than the exponential complexity of non-naive Bayes approaches because it does not use word combination as predictors.
If the task is to classify a test document into a single class, then the class with the highest posterior probability is selected.

Here is one reference:
[1] Tom Mitchell, "Machine Learning", McGraw-Hill, 1997. (Section 6.10)

If you assume each question category as a text type then you can use text categorization.

Naive Bayes classifier is based on Bayes theorem where you assume that all the features(or attribute) are  independent.

It's very easy to implement. You can find many software package with the implementation. e1071 Package in R implements it. Here is the sample code in R which uses naive bayes classifier:

```
N <- nrow(data)
Ntrain <- round(N*0.7)
data <- data[sample(1:N),]
train <- data[1:Ntrain,]
test <- data[(Ntrain+1):N,]
y<-as.factor(train[,13])
x<-train[,3:12]
y_test <- as.factor(test[,13])
x_test <- test[,3:12]
library(e1071)
m <- naiveBayes(x, y) 
pred_test <- predict(m,x_test, type = "class")
pred <- predict(m,x, type = "class")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm would have to maintain a table (or something similar)

```
Word            Category
-------------------------------------
algo            algorithm
design          algorithm
...
...
libraries       library
open            open-source
open-source     open-source
paper           research-paper
research        research-paper
source          source-code
...
```

When you analyze the statement according to this table (after ignoring filler words)

```
1. "Any open source libraries or research papers on this?"

2. open source libraries research papers

3. 
open            open-source
source          source-code
open-source     open-source
libraries       library
research        research-paper
paper           research-paper
research-paper  research-paper

4. by a simple majority, (you can also use a more complex algorithm here,
   like assigning weights to the Categories)
selected category = research paper
```

As you keep on learning using your selected algorithm, your table keeps on getting updated, and you keep getting better results.

Comment: That just might work, but it would take a very long time to create a table of word-tags pairs. How would you detect "research-paper" in this?